# Ordering in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm trying to implement a "custom" ordering in the `ORDER BY` clause in my SQL query using a `CASE` Statement but it's giving me some funky ordering

Here is my `ORDER BY` clause so far:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN 
        CheckInStatus <> 'Cancelled' AND ArrivalTime is null AND GETDATE() > DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME))THEN 1
    WHEN 
        CheckInStatus <> 'Cancelled' AND ArrivalTime is null AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(mi,30, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATETIME)) THEN 2
    WHEN ArrivalTime is not null THEN 3
    WHEN CheckInStatus='Cancelled' THEN 4 
    ELSE 5
    END,
    StartDateTime, ScanTechName
```

What I want to do is order the query as follows:

People who have NOT arrived (and who's appointments are not cancelled) and current time is Greater than than 30 minutes past the StartTime - these guys should be first

People who have NOT arrived (and who's appointments are not cancelled) and current time is less than or equal to 30 minutes past the StartTime - these guys appear second

Next is everyone who is checked in

Followed by Cancelled Appointments

And finally then everything else

And everything will be ordered by StartTime and Name

The issue seems to occur with 2 and 3.  These guys seem to get mixed together and I think it might have to do with my AND but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Below is the error I get in the results - I've included the `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` to visually see the issue

```
Arrival Time            | CheckIn Status | StartDateTime           | OrderStatus
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-15 08:00:07.123 | Arrived        | 2014-08-15 07:15:00.000 | 3 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-15 07:47:48.643 | Arrived        | 2014-08-15 07:30:00.000 | 2
```

So a couple of things happening

1. Since my current GETDATE() is 8/28/2014 - there shouldn't be a 2 Status for the above.  Since it's not Less than or equal to the 30 minutes past the StartDate
2. Since that's wrong in itself it could lead to this second issue - since it's marked as 2 it should be appearing before 3 not after.

Comment: Move the CASE statement into the SELECT clause, so you can clearly see the results. Consider segregating the logic for ArrivalTime and CheckinStatus.

Comment: Since your 2 status includes 'ArrivalTime is null', it's impossible for your second row to have a 2 status.  There must be a mistake in your post.

Comment: Please post the complete query not just the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's doing order based on your selected columns, because when you have a query

```
select empno, empname,sal from emp order by 2,3
```

It will order the query based on empname and then sal as "order by 2,3" means the 2nd and 3rd column. Check your column numbers in select list.